# Web Api basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, mirth

I am down with how Web Api handles authorization out of the box.
I understand how you need to make an initial call to /token, with my credentials, and then get back a nice long Token which i persist on my client side. I then pass:

```
Authorizaion:Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

where xxxxxxxxxx is the token I received initially to all subsequent WebApi calls (which have the [Authorize] annotation).

This is really nice and keeps calls all nice and stateless.

But what happens if the calling app is not in my control?
i.e. I have a 3rd party app (Mirth Connect for those interested).
It will only do 1 call per message (i.e. I cant call the /Token method).

My calling app just asks me for:

- URL
- Method (i.e. POST)
- Username
- Password

so it seems this is expecting normal basic authentication. (I am able to add other header vales, so in theory I could pre load it with the token, but that sounds very clumsy, and the token will eventually expire)

Thanks

Comment: I think you should place a Basic Authentication adapter between the client and you WebAPI.

Comment: found a solution below

Answer (score 1):

found a solution in this article

[Basic Authentication with ASP.NET Web API Using Authentication Filter](http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/basic-authentication-with-asp-net-web-api-using-authentication-filter/)

HE also has another article using Message Handlers, but this seems to do the job